# What does the @ symbol before a variable name mean in C#?

Tags: c#, variables, naming, specifications, reserved-words

I understand that the @ symbol can be used before a string literal to change how the compiler parses the string.  But what does it mean when a variable name is prefixed with the @ symbol?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/91817

Answer (score 811, accepted):

The @ symbol allows you to use reserved word.  For example:

```
int @class = 15;
```

The above works, when the below wouldn't:

```
int class = 15;
```

Comment: With what is it any different than, say, an underscore?

Comment: With an @ symbol, the name is recorded in the assembly as "class", vs. with an underscore it is "_class".  Thus, if another .NET language doesn't define "class" as a reserved word, they could use the name just "class".

Comment: If you used @class for a property name, you could access it like so: MyClass.class instead of MyClass._class

Comment: I think, I could be wrong, in which case, delete my comment

Comment: John, in Delphi, your comment is accurate. Fully qualified names don't need "@" or "&" escaping. Not sure about C#, though.

Comment: It also shows up as just "class" when using reflection.

Comment: You shouldn't prefix public members with an underscore as not all .Net languages support it.

Comment: @Rob: John is correct.
@Michael: Nice simple explanation. +1

Comment: @Vilx- In ASP.net MVC it's very common to use it because that's the only way to express some things. For example if you want to set an element's class attribute you'd type `new { @class = "mc" };` even tho you meant just "class", that's the only way. The point I'm trying to make is that the `@` is **not** part of the actual name of the variable.

Comment: Contrary to some people's comments, this is quite useful.  I had a WSDL which defined an element name as "return" and this allowed me to populate it without reflection (which is what I was contemplating).

Comment: Here is microsoft official documentation link about @character - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/verbatim

Answer (score 485):

The @ symbol serves 2 purposes in C#:

Firstly, it allows you to use a reserved keyword as a variable like this:

```
int @int = 15;
```

The second option lets you specify a string without having to escape any characters. For instance the '\' character is an escape character so typically you would need to do this:

```
var myString = "c:\\myfolder\\myfile.txt"
```

alternatively you can do this:

```
var myString = @"c:\myFolder\myfile.txt"
```

Comment: You still need to escape double quotes by doubling them.

Comment: If you put @ before a string literal, it is called "verbatim string literal".

Comment: Note that with Visual Studio 2015 and up, `$"a string"`allows value interpolation. So `string.Format("Your value is {0}.", value)` can now be `$"Your value is \"{value}\"."`. You can combine these to use literal string interpolation, as in `$@"Your value is ""{value}""."`. (Note the difference in escaping the double quote marks in each version.)

Answer (score 66):

An important point that the other answers forgot, is that "@keyword" is compiled into "keyword" in the CIL.

So if you have a framework that was made in, say, F#, which requires you to define a class with a property named "class", you can actually do it.

It is not *that* useful in practice, but not having it would prevent C# from some forms of language interop.

I usually see it used not for interop, but to avoid the keyword restrictions (usually on local variable names, where this is the *only* effect) ie.

```
private void Foo(){
   int @this = 2;
}
```

but I would strongly discourage that! Just find another name, even if the 'best' name for the variable is one of the reserved names.

Comment: That's probably good advice.  I _think_ that the @ qualifier is the equivalent of VB.Net's square bracket, so the VB equivalent would be:
dim [Class] as Int32 = 15

Comment: @Michael It is exactly the equivalent of VB.NET's square bracket syntax. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6639688/using-keywords-as-identifiers-in-f notes that F# uses double backticks around an identifier for the same purpose.

Comment: As a late comment - "not that it is THAT useful" - in MVC that is the way you can pass forward a property named "class" to the render e - which turns into html "class" to define the CSS class.

Answer (score 17):

It allows you to use a C# keyword as a variable.  For example:

```
class MyClass
{
   public string name { get; set; }
   public string @class { get; set; }
}
```