# C# prefixing parameter names with @

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does the @ symbol before a variable name mean in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/429529/what-does-the-symbol-before-a-variable-name-mean-in-c)
>
> #### Duplicate:
>
> [What does the @ symbol before a variable name mean in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/429529/what-does-the-symbol-before-a-variable-name-mean-in-c)

Sometimes I see some C# code where a method-parameter is prefixed with an @, like this:

```
public static void SomeStaticMethod( SomeType @parameterName ) { }
```

What is the meaning of this ?  Does it has some significant special meaning ?

I am creating an EventListener in NHibernate, and when I let VS.NET generate the interface methods, it generates the OnPostLoad method like this:

```
public class PostLoadEventListener : IPostLoadEventListener
{
    public void OnPostLoad( PostLoadEvent @event )
    {

    }
}
```

Why is this ?

Comment: This is one of those questions that come up reguralry and we could put into a tag-specific FAQ, check the relevant uservoice ticket: http://stackoverflow.uservoice.com/pages/1722-general/suggestions/138261-allow-a-per-tag-home-faq-page

Answer (score 145, accepted):

Try and make a variable named **class** and see what happens -- You'll notice you get an error.

This lets you used reserved words as variable names.

Unrelated, you'll also notice strings prefixed with @ as well -- This isn't the same thing...

```
string says = @"He said ""This literal string lets me use \ normally 
    and even line breaks"".";
```

This allows you to use 'literal' value of the string, meaning you can have new lines or characters without escapes, etc...

Comment: I am familiar with prefixing strings with @ :)  But prefixing variable names was new for me.
Anyway, your explanation is very clear.

Comment: I like this string cross information, might be useful for some readers.

Answer (score 53):

The @ prefix allows you to use reserved words like class, interface, events, etc as variable names in C#. So you can do

```
int @int = 1
```

Comment: That example is going to give me nightmares.

Comment: Ha ha! I know. I hunt such code down ruthlessly and blow it away!

Comment: Perhaps the example should be updated with something like int @double = (int)(1.0/0.0);. Then atleast the whole thing is painful.

Answer (score 23):

event is a C# keyword, the @ is an escape character that allows you to use a keyword as a variable name.

Comment: Which is probably a bad idea...

Comment: I know I always avoid doing this, but it is an available feature.

Comment: Dervin: There are cases when you can't really avoid it, such as interfacing with assemblies written in other languages or previous versions of C#.

Comment: But at the same time kinda necessary when you cannot predict what new keywords may be introduced in future versions of the language... you may after all have a pre 4.0 library that uses 'dynamic' as a symbol name, which you otherwise would no longer be able to fully access from a 4.0 application...

Comment: Since C# 1.0 no new reserved words have been added, only contextual keywords. This will be the case with dynamic as well. http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/11/reserved-and-contextual-keywords.aspx