# Linq, lambda and @

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, lambda

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the use/meaning of the @ character in variable names in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/91817/whats-the-use-meaning-of-the-character-in-variable-names-in-c)
>   [C# prefixing parameter names with @](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038674/c-sharp-prefixing-parameter-names-with)

I feel like I should know this and I find it impossible to google.
Below is an excerpt from some Linq code I came across:

```
private static readonly Func<SomeEntities, someThing, List<someThing>> GetReplacement =
(someEntities, thing) => someEntities.someReplacement.Join(someEntities.someThing,
                           replaces => replaces.new_thing_id,
                           newThing => newThing.thing_id,
                           (rep, newThing) => new {rep, newThing}).Where(
                               @t => @t.rep.thing_id == thing.thing_id).
 Select
 (
     @t => @t.newThing
 ).ToList().Distinct(new SomeThingComparer()).ToList();
```

What does the '@' prefix mean in this context?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Usually, the `@` prefix is used if you need to use a keyword as an identifier, such as a variable name:

```
string @string = "...";
```

The [C# spec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664670.aspx) says the following (emphasis mine):

> The prefix "@" enables the use of keywords as identifiers, which is useful when interfacing with other programming languages. The character @ is not actually part of the identifier, so the identifier might be seen in other languages as a normal identifier, without the prefix. An identifier with an @ prefix is called a verbatim identifier. **Use of the @ prefix for identifiers that are not keywords is permitted, but strongly discouraged as a matter of style.**

Since `t` is not a keyword, I'd say that the `@` should be removed in your example.

Comment: Ha! I knew it was something I should've known. Thanks!