# Using an array of named tuples in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, tuples

I'm trying to use an array of named tuples in a LINQ (LINQ-to-object) query like this:

```
(int from, int to)[] inputRanges = { (1,2), (3,4) };

var result = from range in inputRanges
             select Enumerable.Range(range.from, range.to - range.from + 1);
return result.SelectMany(x => x);
```

However, I receive a compiler error, telling me that `range` has no member `from` and it instead expected a comma `,` instead of `.from`.

What am I doing wrong? Are named tuples and LINQ-to-objects not combinable?

Comment: If I use `.Item1` and `.Item2` instead it works - are named tuples a problem for LINQ? Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `from` is a keyword used by linq for iterating the items of the collection (`from item in collection ...`).

To solve it use `@from` in the linq:

```
var result = from range in inputRanges
             select Enumerable.Range(range.@from, range.to - range.@from + 1);
```

For more about the `@` see: [C# prefixing parameter names with @](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1038674/6400526) . IMO the use of the property name `from` in this case is ok, but I do think in general this would be a bad practice.

Comment: Oh boy...hahaha, thanks. I would have looked for another year without realizing it :D

Comment: @D.R. - :) glad it helped you