# passing css class name to asp.mvc view helper

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html-helper, object-initializers

In ASP.NET MVC view helper, you can do something like

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("click me", "DoSomething", null, new { someAttribute = "a value" } )  %>
```

which will produce the following HTML

```
<a href="DoSomething" someAttribute="a value">click me</a>
```

My question is.... what if I want to set the "class" attribute?

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("click me", "DoSomething", null, new { class = "a-class-name" } )  %>
```

That won't compile because "class" is a reserved word.

Is there a work-around?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, using the [@ literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/429529/what-does-the-symbol-before-a-variable-name-mean-in-c):

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("click me", "DoSomething", null, 
    new { @class = "a-class-name" } )  %>
```