# adding a css class with Html.TextBox

Tags: asp.net, html, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

Trying to add a 'class' html attribute, but I think the keyword 'class' is causing issues.

```
<%: Html.TextBox("name", "value", new {class: " required "})%>
```

Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just prefix 'class' with an '@' as it's a [reserved keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x53a06bb%28VS.71%29.aspx).

```
<%: Html.TextBox("name", "value", new { @class: " required "})%>
```

If you need some background on the @ keyword, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/429529/what-does-the-symbol-before-a-variable-name-mean-in-c) is a good SO question to read.