# Adding Jquery autocomplete to a Html.EditorFor

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, jquery-autocomplete

I want to add an autocomplete (suggestion function) to an editor field in my create menu.

I have this basic razor view  `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title)` and 
I want to add my autocomplete to this.

Previously I have used

```
<input type="text" name="q"  data-autocomplete="@Url.Action("QuickSearch", "Person")" />
<input  type="submit"  name="submit"  value="Find FullName" />
```

And I wondered how to implement this.

My Jquery searches for data-autocomplete

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(":input[data-autocomplete]").each(function () {
        $(this).autocomplete({ source: $(this).attr("data-autocomplete") });
   });
})
```

Comment: check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789512/add-css-class-to-html-editorfor-in-mvc-2

Comment: has anything helped you? or have abandon this question?

Answer (score 1):

You can still do what you previously had

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Title, new { data_autocomplete="/link" })
```

note that this is `TextBoxFor` and not `EditorFor`. Also note the `_` in `data_autocomplete`

I'm not sure about the `Url.Action` part. You may have to build the url yourself by manually inserting a url rather than use url.action.