# razor editorfor checkbox event binding

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, checkboxfor

I cant bind event to @html.editorfor

I've heard it might be connected to presence of "class" attribute but I can see no connection whatsoever.

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.SameAsBaseAddress, new { @onclick = "checkboxcheck()" })

function checkboxcheck() {
    //blah...
}
```

When I debug with firebug and add handler manually all works fine. TextBoxFor, RadioButtonFor etc. have no problems with razor event binding.

What to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `EditorFor` extension doesn't have an argument `htmlAttributes` like the `TextBoxFor`, see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.editorextensions.editorfor%28v=vs.118%29.aspx

I suggest you change `EditorFor` to [`CheckBoxFor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.inputextensions.checkboxfor%28v=vs.118%29.aspx), or if you do want to use the `EditorFor`, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789512/add-css-class-to-html-editorfor-in-mvc-2) suggests to create an editor template.

Answer (score 5):

Modify your EditorFor to use the following instead. I've used this to add html attributes (including classes and onclick) to an EditorFor which generates a checkbox.

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.SameAsBaseAddress, new { htmlAttributes = new { @onclick = "checkboxcheck()" } })
```

You can add more attributes as a comma separated list:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.SameAsBaseAddress, new { htmlAttributes = new { @onclick = "checkboxcheck()", @class = "checkbox" } })
```