# Is there a way to use C# 6's String Interpolation with multi-line string?

Tags: c#-6.0, string-interpolation

Is there a way to use C# 6's String interpolation with multi-line strings ?

Something like

```
   string a = "1111";
   string s = @$"
         {a}    
    ";
```

The above does not work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Long string interpolation lines in C#6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31764898/long-string-interpolation-lines-in-c6)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try swapping the places of `$` and `@`.