# c# code cleanup to break statement in multiple line

Tags: c#, code-cleanup

I have this c# code to make a database. It is working code. But it ugly because of a single line. I want to break it into multiple lines. If I just put line break by the enter key, it gives syntax error. How to beak it a cleaner way:-

```
 string createDataBase = $"CREATE DATABASE {dataBaseName} ON PRIMARY (NAME = {dataBaseName}_Primary, FILENAME = '{primaryPath}'), FILEGROUP {dataBaseName}_FileStreamGroup CONTAINS FILESTREAM(NAME = {dataBaseName}_Filestream, FILENAME = '{filePath}')";
```

Please let me know how to break it?

Comment: add `@` sign after `$` to mark it as a verbatim string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `$@` combination

```
string createDataBase = 
$@"CREATE DATABASE {dataBaseName} 
    ON PRIMARY (NAME = {dataBaseName}_Primary, FILENAME = '{primaryPath}'), 
    FILEGROUP {dataBaseName}_FileStreamGroup 
    CONTAINS FILESTREAM(NAME = {dataBaseName}_Filestream, FILENAME = '{filePath}')
";
```

Comment: You can move `$@"` on same line with `CREATE ..` - will save one redundant line break

Comment: Thanks! it is fine.

Answer (score 0):

You are using an interpolated string.  I believe you can do this:

```
string createDataBase = $@"CREATE DATABASE {dataBaseName} ON PRIMARY (NAME = {dataBaseName}_Primary, FILENAME = '{primaryPath}'), 
FILEGROUP {dataBaseName}_FileStreamGroup CONTAINS FILESTREAM(NAME = 
{dataBaseName}_Filestream, FILENAME = '{filePath}')";
```

As described more here: [Long string interpolation lines in C#6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31764898/long-string-interpolation-lines-in-c6)