# Long string interpolation lines in C#6 don't support Tab,CR and LF

Tags: c#, c#-6.0, string-interpolation

I tried to use string interpolation $""  in C#6 with tabs

```
 var name="My Name";
 var text =$"\t\t{name}";
```

and it's working fine and tabs \t is resolved.

When trying to use [Long string interpolation lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31764898/long-string-interpolation-lines-in-c6)

```
      var name = "myname";
      var text = $@"\t\t{name}
                    tab and name  is in a Long string interpolation \r\n
       ";
    Console.WriteLine(text);
```

output

```
     \t\tmyname
                    tab and name  is in a Long string interpolation \r\n
```

The tab \t ,\r and \n aren't resolved

So i had  to use string.Format() to resolve this issue.

**The question:**

Is this a limitation in the  Long string interpolation for not supporting \t \r \n in c#6 (even c#7)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the verbatim modifier `@` in front of that string, so your tab characters will be un-escaped and treated as normal text. If you want to include them in the string, then you can either enclose the characters in curley brackets (since you're also using the `$` string interpolation modifier) so they're treated as tabs (same with the carriage return and newline characters):

```
    var name = "myname";
    var text = $@"{"\t\t"}{name}
            tab and name  is in a Long string interpolation {"\r\n"}
";
    Console.WriteLine(text);
```

Alternatively, since it's a verbatim string, you can just press <kbd>Tab</kbd> (or <kbd>Enter</kbd>) keys where you want those characters in the string.

This string is the same as the one above:

```
    var text = $@"      {name}
            tab and name  is in a Long string interpolation 

";
```

Comment: "Alternatively, since it's a verbatim string, you can just press Tab" Except if you have plugin or setting that changes tabs to spaces.

Comment: Enclosing the characters in curley brackets resolved  \t \r \n,

Comment: @KennethK. - yes, but if you're living in a state of sin already (following the "spaces are superior to tabs" heathens), you deserve everything you get :-)

Comment: @RufusL you are exactly correct and it seems that whilst i was running through similar topics for VB.NET, I glossed over your second example. Removing.

Answer (score 3):

You are using verbatim string in your second example so `\t` is being escaped. It has nothing to do with string interpolation.

If you want to use tab character don't use verbatim string. You can concatenate multiple lines using string concatenation with `"+"`

Comment: Or, you know, insert a literal tab rather than `\t`. The only thing (Saying this, I'm bound to have forgotten something) you cannot write *literally* in a verbatim string without special work is the double quote.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever You missed one thing that applies to verbatim + interpolated... In the case of a verbatim interpolated string brace escape sequences ({{ and }}) are not interpreted literally; they produce single brace characters.