# C# FormattableString concatenation for multiline interpolation

Tags: c#, string-concatenation, formattablestring

In C#7, I'm trying to use a multiline interpolated string for use with [FormttableString.Invariant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.formattablestring.invariant?view=netframework-4.7.2) but string concatenation appears to be invalid for FormttableString.

Per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.formattablestring?view=netframework-4.7.2): A FormattableString instance may result from an interpolated string in C# or Visual Basic.

The following FormttableString multiline concatenation does not compile:

```
using static System.FormattableString;
string build = Invariant($"{this.x}" 
                       + $"{this.y}"
                       + $"$this.z}");
```

> Error CS1503 - Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to
>   'System.FormattableString'

Using an interpolated string without concatenation does compile:

```
using static System.FormattableString;
string build = Invariant($"{this.x}");
```

How do you implement *multiline* string concatenation with the `FormattableString` type?

<sub>(Please note that FormattableString was added in .Net Framework 4.6.)</sub>

Comment: Can you include the provided reason why it doesn't compile?

Comment: @John, the error code has been added.

Comment: $"{this.x}" is a string, string interpolation is just a syntactic sugar for string format and in this case it doesn't do anything, it's same as using `this.x`, you are trying to pass a string while FormattableString is expected as the error message tells you

Comment: @SelmanGenç - A nonconcatenated interpolated string works fine though.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The Invariant method is expecting the parameter of `FormattableString` [type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.formattablestring.invariant?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_FormattableString_Invariant_System_FormattableString_).
In your case, the parameter  `$"{this.x}" + $"{this.y}"` becomes `"string" + "string'` which will evaluate to `string` type output. That's the reason you are getting the compile error as `Invariant` is expecting the `FormattableString` and not `string`.

You should try this for single line text -

```
public string X { get; set; } = "This is X";
public string Y { get; set; } = "This is Y";
public string Z { get; set; } = "This is Z";
string build = Invariant($"{this.x} {this.y} {this.z}");
```

Output -

> This is X This is Y This is Z

And to implement `multiline` interpolation, you can build the FormattableString  like below and then use the Invarient.

```
FormattableString fs = $@"{this.X}
{this.Y}
{this.Z}";
string build = Invariant(fs);
```

Output -

> This is X
>
> This is Y
>
> This is Z

Comment: Per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.formattablestring?view=netframework-4.7.2): A FormattableString instance may result from an interpolated string in C# or Visual Basic.

Comment: Yes, but you are trying to concatenate 2 interpolated strings which will evaluate to string not FormattableString, updated answer.

Comment: How would you implement a _multliline_ concatenated interpolated string as a `FormattableString`? What would be the proper way to concatenate interpolated strings for use as a `FormattableString`?

Comment: updated my answer, now for multliline concatenation.