# Break code line with Console.WriteLine

Tags: c#

I can't find how to split a Console.WriteLine text without creating a new line in the program. I mean, my code line is too long and it's uncomforable to scroll horizontally in order to check it

```
Console.WriteLine("BlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBla")
```

the result is only a line of text in the console (Might be split because of its length, but keeps being the same line)

into the same, but in different lines in the code, giving the same result. I've tried just splitting them with a new code of line as if it was common code like this:

```
Console.WriteLine("BlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBla
BlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBla
BlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBla
BlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBla")
```

and the result keeps being a line of text in the console

But looks like it's not the right way.

Sorry if it's stupid. Thanks

Comment: No, there's not a way to do that in C# without splitting into multiple lines.

Comment: Thanks, I was going crazy haha

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4086203/426422 (tldr; use the + symbol)

Comment: There is no shame in using Console.Write().

Comment: Thanks guys I forgot about that. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's not a way to split a string literal in C# without embedding the line breaks in the string.  The typical way to split a line like that is:

```
Console.WriteLine("BlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBla" + 
                  "BlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBla" + 
                  "BlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBla" + 
                  "BlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBla");
```

If your string *has* line breaks, then you can use the literal string identifier `@`:

```
Console.WriteLine(@"This is one line followed by a carriage return 
this is the second line of the string
and this is the third line");
```

Comment: Keep in mind that this is annoying as hell to actually edit most of the time

Comment: @MarioOrtiz if you found a question has provide you with an answer you should mark it accepted (I think this answer is the best one here and should be the accepted one). Also answers you found helpful you should upvote.

Comment: Thanks for telling me but looks like i have to wait 5 minutes

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Console.Write` instead and call it multiple times. Call `WriteLine` once at the end either as a part of the all or with an empty string to ensure you start on a new line when you are done with that string.

```
Console.Write("BlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBla");
Console.Write("BlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBla");
Console.Write("BlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBla");
Console.Write("BlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBla");
Console.WriteLine("BlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBla");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Console.WriteLine("BlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBla" +
                  "BlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBla" +
                  "BlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBla" +
                  "BlaBla");
```

If you have Resharper installed hitting enter inside of a string will automatically format the new line and add the + for you.

Comment: Ohhh okay I didnt thought of that. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The best you can do is split long string into substrings and concat them before output:

```
    Console.WriteLine("BlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBla"
 + "BlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBla"
 + "BlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBla")
```

Answer (score -2):

If you only are going to write Bla then do

```
for(int i = 0; i < /*Amount of Bla's here*/; i++){
Console.Write("Bla");
}
```