# What is the @ Sign in front of parameters

Tags: c#, .net, parameters

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does the @ symbol before a variable name mean in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/429529/what-does-the-symbol-before-a-variable-name-mean-in-c)

I have been coding in C# for about a year now, and recently i came across the following

```
public bool OnPreUpdate(PreUpdateEvent @event)
```

As you can see event has an '@' sign before it, is this just to prevent the compiler detecting it as the event type, therefore does '@' gets treated as any other text or is there a special meaning to it?

Comment: @Ardman couldnt find that, i did a search for for similar on here and google,  but nothign usefull come up.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

An `@` sign lets you use C# keywords in identifiers; if you remove the `@` then you'll get a syntax error.

Comment: Thought as much, just wanted to ensure my thoughts were correct as i haven't come across it before, thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

The @ symbol prevents the name from clashing with a C# reserved word.

Answer (score 1):

@ is used in front of keywords so that they are treated as ordinary variables or parameters.