# What does @ mean when creating a SQL query with C#?

Tags: c#, sql

I don't understand what does this `@` means in `HotspotID = @HotspotID`?

```
    public BestFit CheckBestFit(String hotspotID)
    {
        String sql = "SELECT ZoomOut FROM Components WHERE HotspotID = @HotspotID";
        Int32 value = 0;
    }
```

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=what+does+at+sign+mean+in+sql

Comment: Parameters (for prepared statements): [msdn reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4096518/what-is-the-sign-in-front-of-parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bound parameter marker. You'll need to list all bound parameters in the [Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbcommand.parameters%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) collection.

Using bound parameters as opposed to just constructing the SQL text directly helps with security (prevents injection attacks) and performance.

Answer (score 1):

It is the parameter in the query. However it seems as if you are not setting it

Comment: One guy just down-voted all 3 answers in a matter of few seconds. He obviously thinks this question is not worth answering.