# What does '@' at beginning of a variable mean?

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does the @ symbol before a variable name mean in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/429529/what-does-the-symbol-before-a-variable-name-mean-in-c)

I've seen this a couple of times in code that has been passed onto me:

```
try {
   //Do some stuff
}
catch(Exception @exception)
{
   //Do catch stuff
}
```

Can anyone please explain the purpose of the '@' at the beginning of the Exception variable?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/429529/what-does-the-symbol-before-a-variable-name-mean-in-c

Comment: Dupe of a dupe, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/429529/what-does-the-symbol-before-a-variable-name-mean-in-c

Comment: @James I always get ninja'd by my long winded but thoroughly researched answers. I decided to take a shortcut this time. :)

Comment: But I can't... so I'll just stay here and look stupid.

Comment: @James: Don't worry about it! A mod will take care of it (probably with a merger.) :)

Answer (score 4):

It lets you name a variable using a reserved keyword.

For example:

```
var @class = "something"; // OK
var class = "something"; // Compilation error
```

Answer (score 0):

Resharper outputs them sometimes if the name of the variable is close to a class name or a namespace i believe, it is just giving it a unique non clashing name

Comment: The @ is not part of the name, and thus does not add any uniqueness to it. In the example given it is superfluous. ReSharper outputs them (correctly) if the name is a reserved word.

Answer (score 0):

Shameless rip of Michael Meadows answer to a duplicate question follows.

The @ symbol allows you to use reserved word. For example:

```
int @class = 15;
```

The above works, when the below wouldn't:

```
int class = 15;
```