# Dual nature of myClass in C#

Tags: c#, .net

**myclass** is working as **string** as well as **myClass** in below example.

I know everyone will say *this is not a good habit to use something like in below example*.

**CODE:**

```
class myClass
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {   
        string @myClass = "my-Class";

        myClass.Replace("-", " ");  //myClass works as string
        myClass ob = new myClass();  //myClass works as myClass

        ob.i();
    }
    public void i()
    {

    }
}
```

But I want to know:

- Is this a compiler bug? *as compiler should give warning.*
- How compiler manages this dual nature?

Comment: Ow, my eyes! But +1, for now I'm curious too...

Comment: Why should the compiler give a warning? You're using myClass in two totally different contexts, and there is no ambiguity to the compiler.

Comment: The difference is context. The parser can determine based on the context if it's the token is an object or a class.

Comment: but Visual Studio's intellisence is showing only string methods and properties, when I use `myClass. `.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're basically just doing something that looks weird, but the compiler can figure it out based on the context.

```
string @myClass = "my-Class";
```

This is declaring a string variable named myClass.  The use of @ on the variable name allows you to create variables with a name that would normally not be allowed (e.g. a keyword).  In your case, the @ is not needed, as myClass is not a keyword, but you can still use it.  See this question for info:  [What does the @ symbol before a variable name mean in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/429529/what-does-the-symbol-before-a-variable-name-mean-in-c).

```
myClass.Replace("-", " ");
```

This is calling the string Replace method on your myClass variable.

```
myClass ob = new myClass();
```

This is creating a new object of type "myClass".  The compiler can tell by the usage that this use of myClass refers to the type, not the string variable.

Answer (score 2):

Note that you don't even need the `@`:

```
string myClass = "my-Class";
```

The above is perfectly fine.

You say:

```
compiler should give warning.
```

Should it? There is actually no ambiguity.

Consider this pretty typical scenario:

```
public class MyRandom
{
    public Random Random { get; private set; }

    public MyRandom()
    {
        // Is this ambiguous? No--the left HAS to be the property;
        // the right HAS to be the type name.
        Random = new Random();
    }
}
```

It's really not uncommon for names of *variables* to also be names of *types*. Only when some member overlaps is there ambiguity. For example:

```
public class MyThreadPool
{
    public static void Add(Thread thread)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Called the static method.");
    }
}

public class SomeOtherClass
{
    public List<Thread> MyThreadPool { get; private set; }

    public SomeOtherClass()
    {
        MyThreadPool = new List<Thread>();
    }

    public void DoSomethingAmbiguous()
    {
        // To me, it would make sense for the compiler to issue a warning here,
        // as it seems rather ambiguous (to me at least). However, it doesn't,
        // which tells me the behavior is defined somewhere in the spec (I'm too lazy
        // to check).
        MyThreadPool.Add(null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The line below is referring to the string variable you have defined with string @myClass and not the myClass class.

```
myClass.Replace("-", " ");  //myClass works as string
```

Comment: Yes, but why isn't there a name clash at compile-time?

Comment: One is a type, the other is a local variable name.  That's legit.

Comment: @Chris: Aha! So simple, and obvious in retrospect when one often names properties the same as their type. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are using `myclass` as a type as well as a variable name - the compiler can distinguish between the two of them, only if they clash you would have a problem - i.e within your `Main` method this would create a compiler error:

```
myClass.Main(new string [1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The first @myClass is an instance or variable name, this will not conflict with a class(type) name myClass.

So no error or warning.