# Parameter '@email' must be defined

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, mysql-connector

When I try to insert to my DataBase I got error Parameter '@email' must be defined
my code:

```
 MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO users VALUES(@email,@password,@firstName,@LastName,@UserID,@address,@birthday,0)", con);    
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@email, email);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@password, password);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@firstName, firstName);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@LastName, LastName);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@UserID,UserID);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@address, address);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@birthday, birthday);

            /*THE PROBLEM ISNT IN THE DATABASE,THE FOLOOW INSERT STATMENT WORK!"*/
           // MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO users VALUES('evyataresdxez','sdfs','sdfsdf','sdds',33,'sdfsdf','232',0)", con);


            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cmd.Parameters.Clear();
```

I have no problem in the database/code because the code in the comment is work good. thanks

Comment: Try removing the `@` in your AddWithValue call

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to quote your parameter names. As it stands now, you're passing the parameter value as the parameter name:

```
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("email", email);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("password", password);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("firstName", firstName);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("LastName", LastName);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("UserID", UserID);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("address", address);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("birthday", birthday);
```

This only compiled the way you had it because the `@` symbol before a variable name is [valid syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/429534/2101267) and you happened to name your variables the same as the parameter names.

Comment: wow,i tried to fix it 4 hours :D..thank you!!!!