# Split and then combine byte[]

Tags: c#, arrays

So what I'm trying to do is to save a byte[] into my database. If the byte is to long to be send to the database I whould like to split it into two bytes of half the size. However I'm doing something wrong, because when I check that the splittet bytes combined is equal to the original byte is ain't.

My code looks like this:

```
    public File Add(File item)
    {
        try
        {
            if (item == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("item");
            }

            db.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Added;
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch
        {
            File firstHalf = item;
            File lastHalf = item;
            firstHalf.@byte = item.@byte.Take(item.@byte.Length / 2).ToArray();
            lastHalf.@byte = item.@byte.Skip(item.@byte.Length / 2).ToArray();

            byte[] rv = new byte[firstHalf.@byte.Length + firstHalf.@byte.Length];
            System.Buffer.BlockCopy(firstHalf.@byte, 0, rv, 0, firstHalf.@byte.Length);
            System.Buffer.BlockCopy(lastHalf.@byte, 0, rv, firstHalf.@byte.Length, lastHalf.@byte.Length);

            if(rv == item.@byte)
            {
                Add(firstHalf);
                Add(lastHalf);
            }
        }

        return item;
    }
```

**Edit**

```
public partial class File
{
    public int C_id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public byte[] @byte { get; set; }
    public int file_id { get; set; }
    public int fk_folder { get; set; }
    public int fk_profile { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What is `File`? Is it your own class or `System.IO.File`?

Comment: What is it with those `@byte` members? Is that really correct syntax?

Comment: @AndyKorneyev: `File` is a class. I will update the question to include a diffinition of that ^^

Comment: (The @ prefix allows normally reserved words as members)

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar:  Using the `@` prefix before a variable in C# lets you name a variable with a reserved word.  ([see this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/429529/what-does-the-symbol-before-a-variable-name-mean-in-c))

Comment: @AlexK. Thanks. You learn something new every day. Though I'd presume it's easier to come up with a different name. It should be capitalized anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem starts here:

```
File firstHalf = item;
File lastHalf = item;
firstHalf.@byte = item.@byte.Take(item.@byte.Length / 2).ToArray();
```

You just creating new reference to `item` in first line, so then in third line you're corrupting **original** `@byte`.

You need to use deep copy of `item` instead.

One of possible approaches - create `Clone` method in `File` class which will be return new instance of `File` with copied fiedls, and instead of `File firstHalf = item;` it will be `File firstHalf = item.Clone();`

It is first approach came into my mind, probably not the best one. In fact, I can't estimate right now - do you really need two exact copies of your `item` - probably this logic should be refactored.

Comment: This is just the first of a dozen mistakes :(

Comment: @BenVoigt, yes and most obvious one. In fact only this is enough to corrupt source data.

Comment: @BenVoigt: I would love if you could elaborate ;-) I know I'm not the best and would like to learn

Comment: @MichaelTotKorsgaard: Well, the line immediately following does not skip the same number of items taken in the first set.  And then it throws away half the remaining items.  Size of `rv` is not computed correctly.  Comparison is done incorrectly as Alex mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

To compare use `rv.SequenceEqual(item.@byte)` (or a loop) as currently you look to see if they are equal references (which they are not).

Also don't use an Exception for control-of-flow!

Comment: How would you set up a way to control it?

Comment: Just an `else` for the `if (item == null)` ?

Comment: Ah I see. The try-catch was for the `SaveChange` the `if(item == null)` should be before the try-catch ^^ my bad