# Performaing operations on model members

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a view that is using a model. I just need to do a simple subtraction on the model variables using razor.

Here is what the code looks like:

```
    @model Inquiry.Inq_Weights


<table id="mainWeights">

        <tr>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => Model.HotScaleHalfId)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => Model.HotScaleGrossWeight)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => Model.HotScaleTareWeight)</td>
        </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><strong>Total Hot Scale Weight</strong></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td align="right">(@Model.HotScaleGrossWeight - @Model.HotScaleTareWeight;)</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I am trying the `(@Model.HotScaleGrossWeight - @Model.HotScaleTareWeight;)`
but it is just displaying "0 - 0". The zeros are correct at this point. but i don't want it to display the expression, just the result of that operation.
I have also tried using a variable then listing that, as in

```
        @{
        var netWeight = @Model.HotScaleGrossWeight - @Model.HotScaleTareWeight;
        netWeight;
    }
```

But that doesn't work either. How can I do simple math on model members?

Comment: Side note: what do you expect from @{var netWeight = 0;netWeight;} ? That is not even valid C#...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do this:

```
  @(Model.HotScaleGrossWeight - Model.HotScaleTareWeight)
```

With your other example:

```
@{
    var netWeight = Model.HotScaleGrossWeight - Model.HotScaleTareWeight;
 }
```

Then use it with `@netWeight`. Please note that the `@` symbol is razor specific, you don't have prefix your variables with it inside a c# expression. When you write `@` you are actually saying that you are going to write a c# expression. Writing `@` before `Model` is just for the razor engine to know that this is going to be a c# expression (your variable actually) and not a simple text 'Model'.

But I recommend to do this kind of stuff within your controller.

**update**

as Alexei wrote in comment `@` is not just for razor: [What does the @ symbol before a variable name mean in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/429529/what-does-the-symbol-before-a-variable-name-mean-in-c)

Comment: Side note: `@` is not just Razor specific `@Model` is valid for both C# and Razor.