# difference between string and @string for directory

Tags: c#

Sometimes I find that many people use @string for locate a directory than use string even I though that they are same.
for example : 
I have variable that called direct

```
string direct = "C:\\Users";
```

And then,I type :

```
System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(@direct);
```

I think it's same with

```
System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(direct);
```

But,what's difference between @direct and direct?

Comment: Also possible they want to use 'string' as a variable name. @ prefix allows a reserved keyword to be used as a variable name

Comment: @SSS they would need to be sacked

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The @ prefix allows you to use a reserved keyword as a variable name.

The following is an error:

```
string string = "C:\\Junk";
```

but the following is allowed (although a **very bad idea**):

```
string @string = "C:\\Junk";
```

The @ prefix can also be used as a verbatim string literal:

```
string thefolderpath = @"C:\Junk";
```

If I had to guess, I would say the original programmer decided to use `@string`, `@int` etc. for temporary variables, as a style choice. A style choice, it must be said, akin to wearing socks with sandals.

Comment: If a question is clearly a duplicate, please don't answer it. Just vote to close it as a duplicate. There isn't a situation where it's okay to vote to close *and* answer.

Comment: Actually the linked answer is the wrong one, it should be https://stackoverflow.com/questions/429529/what-does-the-symbol-before-a-variable-name-mean-in-c