# Is private a reserved word in c#

Tags: c#

I named a variable `private` in C# and I get below error.

```
bool private = false;
```

> Program.cs(15,12): error CS1001: Identifier expected [/home/ccuser/workspace/csharp-data-types-variables-handling-errors-csharp/e7-workspace.csproj]
>   Program.cs(15,12): error CS1002: ; expected [/home/ccuser/workspace/csharp-data-types-variables-handling-errors-csharp/e7-workspace.csproj]
>   Program.cs(15,12): error CS1513: } expected [/home/ccuser/workspace/csharp-data-types-variables-handling-errors-csharp/e7-workspace.csproj]
>   Program.cs(15,20): error CS1519: Invalid token '=' in class, struct, or interface member declaration [/home/ccuser/workspace/csharp-data-types-variables-handling-errors-csharp/e7-workspace.csproj]
>   Program.cs(21,1): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected [/home/ccuser/workspace/csharp-data-types-variables-handling-errors-csharp/e7-workspace.csproj]

Comment: Yes, but you can use `bool isPrivate = false;`.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, it is a reserved keyword. You can find a full list on the [C# Keywords](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/) page in the docs.

If you really want to use `private` you can prefix it with `@` (i.e. `bool @private = false;`) but you probably should just choose a different name, such as `isPrivate`.

Comment: +1 for the `@`, didn't know about it. Is it only used for this need (creating variable with reserved keyword name)?

Comment: @Daniel I believe so. Of course there's also the [verbatim identifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/verbatim) with strings which uses `@`, although it has a different meaning and usage there.

Comment: There's something else actually :) https://stackoverflow.com/a/429556/11397775

Answer (score 1):

You should use IDE, so you could see straight-away that something is a reserved keyword (alongside with indication of an error), like here in Visual Studio:

[image]

it colors blue all reserved keywords :)

You could pefix it with `@` or `_`, choose any:

[image]