# How to escape identifiers in Boo?

Tags: syntax, boo

If I have an identifier with a same name as existing keyword, how do I escape it?

Comment: hmm, I'm using boo in production about 2 years and never had such a question)) just googled and found nothing.

Comment: I had to read boo grammar to find out more. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what I found (and this is probably the final answer):

1. It is possible to use `@` as a prefix in identifier names. However, by default it creates a different identifier (`@a != a`).
2. Since `@` is allowed, it is possible to add a new compiler step to the pipeline that will do `TrimStart('@')` on all identifiers. It works ok, you will just have to remember all types of things that have names.
3. If you are using Rhino.DSL, it has a UseSymbols step that converts @a into 'a', which had confused me a lot (I was working with project that included this step by default).

Comment: and how that work?? how code like that can be produced to AST?   ''class = "Hello I'm keyword"''
yes you can wrote @class, but it is _not_ a keyword. Also you should be able do than in different levels of a type i.e. fields, parameters, properties, methods etc. It's not an easy task ))

Comment: also you should check that
a = "Hello"
@a = "Hello"
after your step you can get non uniq names

Comment: _yes you can wrote @class, but it is not a keyword_ -- well, the difference is not obvious when you stay inside Boo, but consider a calling application in some other language where, for example, 'def' is not a keyword. In this case, difference between 'def _def()' and 'def @def()' is that it would be callable as 'x._def()' in the first case , and 'x.def()' in the second.

Comment: as for the unique names, I know it, but it is the same as C# does it, so I (and other users) am quite accustomed to this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think anything like the [C# @ prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/91817/whats-the-use-meaning-of-the-character-in-variable-names-in-c) is implemented in Boo... but I'm pretty sure it could be achieved by inserting a custom compiler step to the beginning of the compiler pipeline.

Comment: I think it is not possible at all. compiler steps operates on AST. but which AST will be produced for such a code
    class = 'Hello'

Comment: Added my finding as an answer.

Comment: so it *was* possible with a compiler step after all

Comment: yes, and I am ok with compiler steps, but I was hoping that there is something that works out of the box.