# C# @ in enum generated classes from XSD

Tags: c#, enums, xsd

Using xsd.exe I've got an enum which has an @ symbol in front of one of the elements. I can't work out why, and I can't work out what it's for or what it means. Searching Google for a symbol isn't terribly productive.

Original XSD fragment:

```
  <xs:simpleType name="stopLocation">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:enumeration value="default"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="near"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="far"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="nearExact"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="farExact"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
```

Generated class fragment:

```
public enum stopLocation {
    @default,
    near,
    far,
    nearExact,
    farExact,
}
```

(Yes, the final element has a comma which VS seems happy with)

Thanks.

Comment: probably because default is a C# keyword.

Comment: `default` is a reserved keyword; the `@` prefacing a reserved keyword lets you use it as a legal identifier (using it is a smell IMO (especially the disgusting `@this`)). The seemingly-extraneous `,` is legal as per the specification. It makes code maintenance and code generation a little bit easier.

Comment: Ah, I was focusing on the @ being part of the enum rather than as a language feature - makes sense now! I'd never had the need to use it, hence not knowing it until now. I'll see if I can get the inherited XSD changed. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It escapes the `default` keyword from C#.

See this question: [What's the use/meaning of the @ character in variable names in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/91817/whats-the-use-meaning-of-the-character-in-variable-names-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because the enum value name (default) is a reserved word. In C# reserved words must be appended with an `@` so the compiler knows how to interpret them.

You would see the same behavior with a name like 'event' or 'public'.

Answer (score 1):

[default](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/25tdedf5%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) is a C# keyword.

The `@` symbol is used as a way to escape language keywords so that they can be used as variable names and other identifiers.

Answer (score 0):

http://dotnetdud.blogspot.com/2008/12/how-to-use-reserved-words-in-net-c.html

The "@" syntax allows you to use a reserved language word as a variable/member name. I would consider it poor practice in most cases.