# '@' symbol prefix on c# method call?

Tags: c#, .net, method-call

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the use/meaning of the @ character in variable names in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/91817/whats-the-use-meaning-of-the-character-in-variable-names-in-c)

I was doing some .net development and I noticed I could add an **@** symbol before any method call, i.e.:

```
var message = dog.@SayHello();
```

Just wondering, why is the reason this can be done ??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/91817/whats-the-use-meaning-of-the-character-in-variable-names-in-c

Answer (score 10):

The `@` symbol can escape keywords and turn them into ordinary identifiers. Most .net languages support a mechanism like this since keywords are language dependent, and thus code written in other languages might collide with a keyword in your language without even noticing it.

Some people like using `@this` for the first parameter extension methods.

```
public static void MyExtension(this MyType @this)
```

another scenario where this can be useful is when using members to represent html attributes. Then without this feature you could not represent the `class` attribute.

Answer (score 6):

An `@` symbol can be pre-fixed to any identifier in case you're interoperating with code written in another language that uses C# keywords as identifiers:

```
object @class; //allowed
object class;  //error
```

Answer (score 6):

This is simply part of the [definition of a valid identifier in C#.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664670%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

`@` lets you use an identifier that would otherwise be interpreted as a keyword.

For example, if you want to have a variable named class, you can write this:

```
int @class;
```

Of course, because you can do it doesn't mean it's a good idea to do it.

Some situations where it's useful is code generators that create C# code from a template or external source. e.g. `xsd.exe` is an SDK command-line tool creates C# classes that back up an XML schema. If your XML schema contains an element or attribute name that is reserved in C# (such as class), `xsd.exe` would preserve the name in the matching C# class but it would prefix it with a `@`.

Answer (score 1):

It's a case of just because we *can*, doesn't mean we *should*.