# "@" inside a string?

Tags: c#

Now, I know what @ operator is for - it allows to use reserved word as variable name or make non-escaping string, but recently I've received codebase which contain this (names changed and parts of string as I'm under NDA):

```
somestring = @"This is good thing that @nametag is there";
```

Obviously it seems to be some kind of placeholder, but what it exactly does?

Comment: It's nothing native to C# as far as I know.  Probably a tokenized string for use by the codebase itself.

Comment: By default, it’s just a character inside a string. But it could be used by something that processes the string and replaces the part with something else. Now we can’t tell you what in your code does that.

Comment: Could you give a bit more context. This could mean anything, depending on your code. The language itself assigns no special meaning to an @ inside a string literal.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/91817/whats-the-use-meaning-of-the-character-in-variable-names-in-c

Answer (score 3):

Likely a placeholder to be replaced at runtime

For example:

Dear @CustomerName,

Join the first ever event in @City at @Time on @Date

...