# @ViewBag vs ViewBag in controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I downloaded a sample project and noticed the author was using `@ViewBag` when assigning data to ViewBag inside the controller, in all the examples I have seen `ViewBag` was used but running the project I downloaded showed that using `@ViewBag` works find so I am now a bit confused. Is there any difference between using `@ViewBag` and `ViewBag` inside the controller?

Comment: Are you sure this was in the controller and not in the view?

Comment: Yes it was in the controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@ViewBag` works in the controller but it's not necessary, and likely a mistake from the author.

The reason it works is described in [What's the use/meaning of the @ character in variable names in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/91817/whats-the-use-meaning-of-the-character-in-variable-names-in-c), `@` can be used to escape variable names that are also language keywords.

Comment: Likewise i've seen folks write in Razor 1.0 @if (@myvar > 5).

This does not work in latest Razor versions.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure @ViewBag in the controller?
In Razor (the view engine asp .net mvc use) uses @ to indicate you want to write some c# code.

so essentially @ViewBag (use in Razor) and ViewBag (Use in controller) is the same thing.

for some basic razore rules, read this:
http://www.asp.net/web-pages/tutorials/basics/2-introduction-to-asp-net-web-programming-using-the-razor-syntax

Comment: I am 100% sure it was in the controller.