# The code returns the wrong variable

Tags: c#, sql-server

So this should return `@rez`, but instead it returns `@idCEL`. Why?

```
int rez=0;
var cmd = new SqlCommand(@"exec spUpdateCELPowerMeasurementForGeoData1
                         @idCEL, @rez OUT", conn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idCEL",idCEL).Direction=System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rez", rez).Direction=System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;
cmd.CommandTimeout=700;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

rez = int.Parse(cmd.Parameters[@rez].Value.ToString());

return rez;
```

Comment: It would never do so! You can see that in `return rez` line too.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use quotes around `@rez` - it should be a string:

```
rez = int.Parse(cmd.Parameters["@rez"].Value.ToString());
```

[`@rez` is actually the `rez` local variable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/91817/7586), not the "rez" sql parameter. It is always zero, so you are getting the first parameter instead.

I'd also avoid using `ToString` and `Parse`. If your stored procedure is returning a number, you can simply do `(int)cmd.Parameters["@rez"].Value`, or [`Convert.ToInt32`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/23511zys.aspx)