# Using @ prefix for variable name

Tags: c#, .net, naming-conventions, reserved-words

In my domain model I have an Event entity. This means that I have to sometimes declare variables as: @event since event is a reserved key word.

I've read on a few stack overflow posts (like [What's the use/meaning of the @ character in variable names in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/91817/whats-the-use-meaning-of-the-character-in-variable-names-in-c)) that this is not recommended unless you're interacting with other programming languages. My question is why is it not recommended? What is the issue with using @?

I could use an "Occasion" entity instead but that would mean in my UI layer I would have events which maps to occasions?

Comment: Please add references to the `few stack overflow posts` that call the practice into question.  My personal take is that it would cause confusion and leave room for errors.

Comment: There is nothing technically wrong with `@variableName`, so I don't think it is possible to give good concrete non-opinion based answer to this question...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov If that is the case then I think i can justify using it in this particular scenario. I just wanted to make sure i wasn't missing something.

Comment: @EricJ. I see your point but it would also cause confusion mapping between an Occasion entity to an EventDTO.

Comment: Just be careful to not confuse everyone... Something like `dynamic dynamic = 4;` or `var @if = true; if(@if)...` is valid C#, but not necessary immediately readable.

Comment: haha that gives me a headache just looking at it. The only time it is an issue is when I have an event entity as a parameter. Ends up being MethodName(Event @event);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're trying to do is the entire purpose of the @ prefix to prevent name clashes.

But this text from MSDN says everything you're asking:

> The prefix "@" enables the use of keywords as identifiers, which is
> useful when interfacing with other programming languages. The
> character @ is not actually part of the identifier, so the identifier
> might be seen in other languages as a normal identifier, without the
> prefix. An identifier with an @ prefix is called a verbatim
> identifier. Use of the @ prefix for identifiers that are not keywords
> is permitted, but *strongly discouraged as a matter of style*.

[**Source**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/lexical-structure#identifiers)

So it just comes down to style, in your case it's the right solution if you don't want to rename your entity.