# VB.net conversion to c#

Tags: c#, vb.net

I am converting a section of code from VB.net to C# and I am stuck in this section

```
If Not IsNothing(successNode) Then
    Dim _data As XElement = (From xml In xDoc.Descendants("data") Select xml).FirstOrDefault
    Dim _count As Integer = _data.@count
    If _count > 0 Then
        _objectCollection = New QueryObjectCollection(_data.@listtype)
        For Each item As XElement In _data.Elements(_data.@listtype)
            If Not IsNothing(item.<RECORDNO>) Then
                _objectCollection.Keys.Add(item.<RECORDNO>.Value)
                _objectCollection.Objects.Add(item)
            End If
        Next
    End If
End if
```

Not sure what is `_data.@count` and `_data.@listtype`. Is there are equivalent fuunction ic C#?

Can someone help me convert this section of code to c#?

Comment: I would load up ILspy or similar and look at the C# output, tweak as necessary..

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/91817/whats-the-use-meaning-of-the-character-in-variable-names-in-c

Comment: Keep in mid that there are converters available to convert VB.Net code to C#. Apparently some of the online converters do not handle the XML literals in your code, but I find that Tangible's [Instant VB](http://www.tangiblesoftwaresolutions.com/Free_Editions.html) handles more of the tricky cases (including this one). Note that I am not connected to Tangible other than as a user of the free versions of their software.

Answer (score 10):

It's just VB shorthand.

In VB:

```basic
_data.@count
_data.@listtype
```

In C#:

```
_data.Attribute("count").Value
_data.Attribute("listtype").Value
```

Specifically, this is part of a VB.Net language feature of called "XML Literals", and is used in conjunction with LINQ to XML.  (C# has LINQ, but does not have XML literals.)

The `.@name` notation in the VB code, when used on an `XElement` denotes that you want to retrieve an *attribute* from that XML element with the specified name.  There is also a VB syntax which looks like `...<name>` to retrieve an *element* of the specified name, which would map to the C# `.Element("name").Value`.

See [Overview of LINQ to XML in Visual Basic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384460.aspx), and [XML Literals Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384629.aspx).

Answer (score 6):

@ is used to access XAttributes on the XElement represented by _data (whereas the <> notation accesses child XElements).
Your C# port should look something like this:

```
if (successNode != null)
{
    var _data = xDoc.Descendants("data").FirstOrDefault();
    var _count = int.Parse(_data.Attribute("count").Value);
    if(_count > 0)
    {
        var listType = _data.Attribute("listtype").Value;
        _objectCollection = new QueryObjectCollection(listType);
        foreach (var item in _data.Elements(listType))
        {
            var recordNo = item.Element("RECORDNO");
            if (recordNo != null)
            {
                _objectCollection.Keys.Add(recordNo.Value);
                _objectCollection.Objects.Add(item);
            }
        }
    }
}
```