# c# Regular Expression no match - when there should be

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to match 0 or more strings of letters, numbers, and white space between quotation marks ("), these sets can be separated by white space or not, and the string will start with a key word to identify what to do with the matched sets.

The simplest example is below:

```
\\ inString = test "1" "a""3";
Regex regEx = new Regex("@(\"[0-9 a-z]*\")", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
Match match = regEx.Match(inStr);
```

The match is not a success, let alone containing the 3 expected results

However via http://regexhero.net the match is a success - I'm using regexhero as its SilverLight based so is using the .NET Regex engine...

Regexhero settings:

Regular Expression

```
(\"[0-9 a-z]*\")
```

Target String

```
test "1" "b""3"
```

Result

```
1: "1"
1: "b"
1: "3"
```

Can anyone explain whats wrong with my implementation?

Comment: Double quotes in a verbatim string literal must be declared with `""`. I guess you wanted `@"""[0-9 a-z]*"""`. See the [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%22%5b0-9+a-z%5d*%22&i=test+%221%22+%22a%22%223%22) of the regex. I think this is just a typo. I suggest closing the question.

Comment: i just noticed that the @ is within the string. why is it there? if it is outside,  you would need double quotes (as @WiktorStribiżew pointed out). it doesnt make any sense inside

Comment: Accepted the answer below - yes it was a typo.

Comment: @Morvael look my answer You have to change something more

Comment: @goodeinstein Yes I know - it was just sample code, the actual implementation looks little like the code in the question. It was simply that I had put the @ in the wrong place and then developed a blind spot for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I expect your regex is meant to be:

```
Regex regEx = new Regex("(\"[0-9 a-z]*\")", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

or (exactly the same)

```
Regex regEx = new Regex(@"(""[0-9 a-z]*"")", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

It looks like this question might be a fruitful read for you:

[What's the use/meaning of the @ character in variable names in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/91817/whats-the-use-meaning-of-the-character-in-variable-names-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

You must change the regexp patern:

```
"@(\"[0-9 a-z]*\")"
```

to

```
@"(""[0-9 a-z]*"")"
```

**Also You need change**

```
Match match = regEx.Match(inStr);
```

to

```
MatchCollection match = regEx.Matches(intstr);
```

Because `Matches` searches an input string for all occurrences of a regular expression and returns all the matches but `Match` searches the specified input string for the **first occurrence** of the regular expression

If You want result like this:

```
1: "1"
1: "b"
1: "3"
```

You need to change to `Matches`