# How to login with newly created server name in sql server 2008

Tags: c#, sql-server, authentication, server-name

> Basically problem starts from my c# code. it is showing error in my
>   connection string. In connection i mentioned server name like,
>   `Chaitanya\SQLEXPRESS` and at compile time it shows the error at " \
>   ".

**My Connection string**

```
 SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Server=Chaitanya\SQLEXPRESS;user Id=sa;password=sa@12;Database=err");
```

Now i am trying to change my sql server name and for this i created one server name. First i used this command `sp_dropserver` and then `sp_addserver` finally restart. The Server name is created successfully. but unable to login. So i create a new login ,and it is created , but for current logged in server only. 
Now how can i do...?? how to login using newly created login..?? or how to change the server name of created login account..??
sorry for if any mistakes in question...

Comment: Post your connection code and the actual error you get. We can't help without information.

Comment: you need to add like "servername\\instancename " or @"servername\instancename"

Comment: You haven't selected a database within the server to work with.

Comment: @TheGameiswar you mean  "Chaitanya\SQLEXPRESS" replace by "Chaitanya\\SQLEXPRESS"

Comment: @Takarii, sorry.. but what..??

Comment: use this as guidance (its what i use for my remote connection) `Server=192.168.1.82,1433; Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=myDB;User ID=myUsername;Password=myPassword` where the ip is the servername, and 1433 is the defaul sql server port

Comment: yes @TheGameiswar it works... i want to give you your credit...

Comment: @Takarii i am using sql server on my system..

Comment: Note, for future reference you can get all the connection string parameters from [www.connectionstrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com)

Comment: (im also using sqlserver)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\ stands for escape character and is a reserved keyword.so in your case ,you need to add  \\  .More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/91817/whats-the-use-meaning-of-the-character-in-variable-names-in-c)

```
Chaitanya\\SQLEXPRESS

or
@symbol before connection string..

(@"Server=Chaitanya\SQLEXPRESS;user
```