# Make "params" a legal variable name

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I have a JSON data to post to http, this JSON data has a var named params:

```
{
 "method": "...",
 "params": [ ... ],
 "session": "...",
 "id": 1
}
```

I want to link every request and response to a class in my Models.
How can I either use the name params for the attribute or make the attribute name change as I serialize my class to JSON format? 
I am using ASP.NET MVC 4 and JSON.NET framework on visual studio 2013 Ultimate edition.

Comment: How are you serialising? Have you tried using the `JsonProperty` attribute?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

A property named `params` (or any other keyword) can be used in C# classes as long as you escape the name [using the @ prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/q/91817/87698):

```
class MyClass
{
    public string method { get; set; }
    public Whatever @params { get; set; }
}
```