# C# INSERT INTO isn`t working (web sql)

Tags: c#, sql, web

I looked in the forum a lot and researched for my problem but I couldn`t find something that helped me.
I have tried a lot of suggestions from here.
I have a site and 3 sign up pages. every page have some information, validators are already set up and I built an SQL Server (Microsoft visual studio community 2015). Here is the code of the first sign up page:

**EDIT**
The problem was that Table is a reserved word, I just had to write [Table] instead of Table in the sqlCommand

Any help will be estimated.

Comment: Are you getting any error

Comment: No, I am not receiving any errors

Comment: You should not be connecting directly to an mdf file.  You may not have credentials and you may be writing to the wrong database.  Use the database name in the SQL Server.  The server already knows the file name when it was attached.  You connection string just needs the name of the server.  You can add a 'USE database_name' statement to select the correct database (you may have more than one database in the server).

Comment: My Database name is Database.mdf...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add quotes around your parameters when assigning a value:

```
sqlCommand.Parameters["@email"].Value = email;
sqlCommand.Parameters["@username"].Value = userName;
```

The reason why you need quotes is because in your case `@email` and `email` refers to the same string variable. You can read more about `@` symbol in C# in answers to [What's the use/meaning of the @ character in variable names in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/91817/whats-the-use-meaning-of-the-character-in-variable-names-in-c)

I'm not 100% sure it code above works or not, if not - you then you should use method [`Add`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/40959t6x(v=vs.110).aspx) or [`AddWithValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue(v=vs.110).aspx). Regardless of the method you should use `"@email"` instead of `@email`.

For recommendation why to use `Add` in favor of `AddWithValue` please refer to [this article](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/).

**EDIT:** It seems the issue is different. In your code you assign `email` and `username` to `null`:

```
string email = null, userName = null;
```

Then nowhere in the code you change these values, i.e. they still remain `null`. Then when you get to this line:

```
if (email != null && userName != null)
```

your values are still `null`, and the logic inside `if` statement is never executed. Fix this part of the code first, and then my initial answer will become helpful as well.

**UPDATE 2** SQL Parameters collection does not contain the parameters, so it needs to be performed using `Add` method:

```
sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@email", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = email;
sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@userName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 12).Value = userName;
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try it

Comment: still not working... I think I have a problem in my SQL script, I will attach it to the question

Comment: @D4NieLDev I updated the answer above. It seems your `if` statement is never executed

Comment: I have assigned them to null in the beginning but I have required field validators for both variables.

Comment: @D4NieLDev The only place where you assign a value to `email` is after you perform `Response.Redirect`. So you redirect a user to a different page and SQL statement is not executed once again

Comment: OK I will try another option without this if

Comment: I have tried your solution the new code is above in the question, but I am now getting this error:

Exception Details: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: An SqlParameter with ParameterName '@email' is not contained by this SqlParameterCollection.

Comment: OK I understood you, look at my new code I have updated it

Comment: @D4NieLDev Look at the Update 2 from the answer. Make sure to use method `Add`

Comment: OK I'll try it. thanks for the help you are really useful

Comment: Now I have another problem:
**Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Table'.**
On the row: **sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();**

Comment: @D4NieLDev Table is reserved keyword, try using `INSERT INTO [Table] ...` instead