# Get Exact Name Of Enum Element In C#

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, enums

I have an assembly file that defines an `enum` as the following:

```
public enum DataType{  
    @byte,  
    @short,  
    @int,  
    @long,
    ...  
}
```

When I get its names by calling the `typeof(DataType).GetEnumNames()` or `Enum.GetNames(typeof(DataType))` methods, I will get the following string literals:
`["byte", "short", "int", "long", ...]`.
How can I get the exact name of the elements?
Is there any mistake in naming the enum elements?

Comment: Those are exact names. You can read more http://stackoverflow.com/questions/91817/whats-the-use-meaning-of-the-character-in-variable-names-in-c.

Answer (score 2):

You actually got the correct name for those fields in the enum. As stated in MSDN:

> Keywords are predefined, reserved identifiers that have special meanings to the compiler. They cannot be used as identifiers in your program unless they include @ as a prefix. For example, @if is a valid identifier but if is not because if is a keyword.[1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x53a06bb.aspx)