# What kind of syntax is this? (asp.net mvc C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I copied a line from razor view to my .cs file by mistake, and it can be compiled. why? and what's the difference between the marked 2 lines? thanks.
[image]

Comment: how about rebuild all?

Comment: There is no difference in code. both works same.

Comment: It's called the [verbatim identifier](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/91817/whats-the-use-meaning-of-the-character-in-variable-names-in-c)