# Why using '@' character when use XML (System.Xml)

Tags: c#, xml, xmldocument

What's the difference between:

```
XmlDocumentFragment docFrag = xmlDoc.CreateDocumentFragment();
docFrag.InnerXml = @myString;
```

and

```
XmlDocumentFragment docFrag = xmlDoc.CreateDocumentFragment();
docFrag.InnerXml = myString;
```

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking?

Comment: Are you saying `myString` is a variable or a string literal? I don't understand why you'd change the variable name for the 2nd snippet if the only difference was the `@`.

Comment: It's very unclear what exactly you're asking? Could you perhaps elaborate on what issue you're experiencing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the use/meaning of the @ character in variable names in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/91817/whats-the-use-meaning-of-the-character-in-variable-names-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

The only case when you should use `@` with *variable name* - is when variable name conflicts with keyword. E.g. if you have variable names like `@string` or `@class`. In this particular case you don't need to use `@`.

It is possible also to declare [verbatim string literals](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090.aspx) with `@` symbol, but you should use string literal instead of variable in that case:

```
     docFrag.InnerXml = 
@"<foo>
   <bar/>
</foo>";
```

Such string literals might span multiple lines, which is handy when you work with xml.