# C#: Symbols in front of Variable

Tags: c#

I've seen code that has &, *, and ^ in front of variable names, but searching online only brings up the meaning for @.
What do the original 3 mean? Are there any others like this?

3 Snippets:

```
static bool FName(array<double, 2> ^matrix)

pin_ptr<const double> p_pdMatrix = &matrix[0, 0];

sum += *(pdRoot + c + j * nSize)
```

Secondary: How would you search for the meaning for simple operators such as these? The above is probably a duplicate, but my searches reveal nothing.

Comment: Could you give examples?

Comment: What leads you to believe it's C#?  (Hint: it's not - at least not the first two snippets.)  What kind of codebase were you looking at that used these symbols?

Comment: Dude - it looks like Microsoft's flavor of .Net C++ ("CLI") to me...  Not C#.  For example: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yk97tc08.aspx

Comment: I think you are both right. It was not one of the developers who told me it was C#, so they must have been mistaken. I know they do deal with .NET, though.

Comment: It's certainly C++, because you can't use `<const double>` token (it will treated as generic token). C# uses `<double>` token for `double` generic type parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are used in C# for [Unsafe Code and Pointers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/unsafe-code-pointers/). They work pretty similarly to C++ pointers, but usually also require pinning the object in memory to avoid the garbage collector moving them.
They are [unary operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/#unary-operators) (i.e. they *do something* on the value), unlike `@` which is only used for [explicit parsing of reserved words as variable names](https://stackoverflow.com/q/91817/7586).

Here's a quick example from [`unsafe` (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/unsafe)

```
// compile with: -unsafe

class UnsafeTest
{
   // Unsafe method: takes pointer to int:
   unsafe static void SquarePtrParam(int* p)
   {
      *p *= *p;
   }

   unsafe static void Main()
   {
      int i = 5;
      // Unsafe method: uses address-of operator (&):
      SquarePtrParam(&i);
      Console.WriteLine(i);
   }
}
// Output: 25
```

All of these have additional meaning as safe operators - bitwise `xor`, bitwise `and`, and multiplication - but it is unlikely that's the case - usually this usage is clear.

Looking more closely - unary `^` is not included in C#, so the above comment is probably right - you may be looking at [C++/CLI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/68td296t.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

`&` and `*` have multiple meanings in c#; including a double meaning when used as operators.

For information on how to use them as operators you can go to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/

## Option 1. Logical operators

`&`, `*` and `^` can all be used as logical operators. For example:

```
    // Logical exclusive-OR


    // When one operand is true and the other is false, exclusive-OR 
    // returns True.
    bool b1 = true;
    bool b2 = false;
    Console.WriteLine(b1 ^ b2);
    // When both operands are false, exclusive-OR returns False.
    bool b1 = false;
    bool b2 = false;
    Console.WriteLine(b1 ^ b2);

    // When both operands are true, exclusive-OR returns False.
    bool b1 = true;
    bool b2 = true;
    Console.WriteLine(b1 ^ b2);
```

---

## Option 2. Pointers

`&` and `*` can be used with pointers in c#.

From  [* Operator (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/multiplication-operator):

> also serves as the dereference operator, which allows reading and writing to a pointer.

From [& Operator (C# Reference)](http://%20https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/and-operator)

> The unary & operator returns the address of its operand (requires unsafe context).

There are some examples with both `*` and `&` in the [Pointer types (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/unsafe-code-pointers/pointer-types)

```
// Normal pointer to an object.
int[] a = new int[5] { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50 };
// Must be in unsafe code to use interior pointers.
unsafe
{
    // Must pin object on heap so that it doesn't move while using interior pointers.
    fixed (int* p = &a[0])
    {
        // p is pinned as well as object, so create another pointer to show incrementing it.
        int* p2 = p;
        Console.WriteLine(*p2);

        ...more here...
```

## How to search :)

I just put `c# ^` in my fav search engine and got to the docos.

Here's the proof :)

[image]