# How to use a user defined property named Action

Tags: c#

I'm using Visual Studio 2017

I have a model called `Request`, in that model I have a property:

```
 public string Action { get; set; }
```

now when I instantiate the class I can't access the property 
for the reason it directs me to

```
public delegate void Action()
```

[image]

I know it's wrong to make that kind of properties but I can't change it.

Comment: Why the weirdly scribbled on image? Where is `public delegate void Action()` defined?

Comment: It is not wrong to make these properties and the compiler can handle it. Just write `Action = "value",`.

Comment: Please edit your question and include your actual code and not an image of your code.

Comment: This code is invalid and you have red underline from intellisense. All the rest (*"I can't access the property"* and *" it directs me to ..."*) seems to be simply thoughts. It's highlighted, because intellisense at that point is not yet able to determine what this will be property and probably the easier *match* is to the type. But this is not a problem, nor the bug.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you haven't typed out the correct code yet, so the compiler tries to make sense of what you *did* type. Do it right and it will work:

```
Request = new Request
{
    // other fields...

    Action = "Text"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, you're in the situation where the field name is the same as a pre-defined class name or a language clause or etc. It's not a problem if you use so called "verbatim" names format (a name preceded with `@` symbol).

```
Request = new Request
{
    // other fields...

    @Action = "Text"
}
```

That way, you can have such field names as @var, @params, @yield and so on. Take a look here as an example:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/92045/1964969