# API with an parameter named with keyword word in c#

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, webapi

One of the API calling from outside company to our use the parameter name "ref". They asking us to create the web api which accept this parameter. We are writing in C# Web Api and "ref" is a keyword and wont able to do that. Any work around?

> https://xxxxxxxxx/xxx/xxx/xxxxx/?ref=1234

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can accept `ref` as a parameter using`@` symbol in front of your field:

```
public JsonResult MyMethod(string @ref)
```

You can read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/91817/whats-the-use-meaning-of-the-character-in-variable-names-in-c)

Comment: already upvoted...can marked as answer after some minutes...will def do..

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the `Name` property of [FromUriAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.http.fromuriattribute?view=aspnetcore-2.2):

```
public JsonResult MyMethod([FromUri(Name = "ref")] string reference)
```

Comment: thank u..one more new thing learned...