# c# Anonymous type. How to use datatype name as member name

Tags: c#, anonymous-types

I have to create a json query dynamically where one of the properties is called "bool". I need this name because the system I send the requests to, expects this naming.

To create the json I use C# anonymous types like:

```
var myquery = new { bool = "Yes" };
```

but I'm not allowed to use bool as member name. Is there a fix for that somehow?

I have searched for a solution, without any success. I hope there is an easy fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you put the `@` character in front of the variable.

```
var myquery = new { @bool = "Yes" };
```

Comment: For more informations https://stackoverflow.com/questions/91817/whats-the-use-meaning-of-the-character-in-variable-names-in-c

Comment: Thanks exactly what I was hoping for :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can prefix it with an `@`.

```
var myquery = new { @bool = "Yes" };
```